# Why has my mesh got these jagged lines

Tags: mesh

[image][image]I need to get rid of these jagged lines in my render. I created the text then used a wave modifier and converted the text to a mesh. I then added the velvet modifier and feel like it has something to do with the velvet modifier but may be wrong. Il attach another pic of the file nearer to completion and show how it is just a few vertices that ruin it! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure the shading artifact is caused by ngons or bad topology, try removing doubles and making sure all your faces are tris and quads, lastly press ctrl n in edit mode. if none of these fix it can i see edit mode shaded view and your node setup?

Comment: I fixed the problem now after reading the thread Ray linked! I had to apply a remesh modifier before converting to a mesh and adding the wave modifier. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Having the same problem again... If I do it that way the file becomes huge after having to bump up the 'octree depth' enough for the text to look similar to how it should.